# Multicast IP address over LAN

Tags: java, sockets, multicast

I am creating a chatting application on peer to peer network.

I am trying to write code that will  allow me to detect which computers have the application installed and if it is running (So that I can show who is online).

I thought that program will multicast the IP address on which that program is running and others will detect that multicast IP and add them to the list for displaying online users..

Please tell me how to write the program for this.

or tell me any other logic for this application to show on which pc my application is running

Comment: Please tell me how to write the program for this

Comment: Please tell me how you've attempted to write the program for this so far, what problems you are seeing, the relevant code, and what you've tried to do to resolve your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect clients that have the application installed, you will need to setup a service or program that always executes in the background. Why do you need to check who has it installed?

For detecting if it is running you can simply execute code like what I've outlined below in  your programs.

For your server you will want to run a thread such as this;

```
class MultiCastServerThread extends Thread {
    protected DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    protected String multicastGroupId = "224.0.0.224";
    protected long delay = 1000l;
    protected int port = 2244;

    public MultiCastServerThread() throws IOException {
        super("SpeakServerThread");
    }

    public void run() {
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(multicastGroupId);
        while (true) {
            try {
                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                buf = "Message".getBytes();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, group, port);
                socket.send(packet);
                sleep(delay);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                socket.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It multicasts the message "Message" every second to the multicast group `224.0.0.224`.

For your client you will want to call a method such as;

```
final String MULTICAST_GROUP = "224.0.0.224";
final int PORT = 2244;
public String getMultiCast() {
    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(PORT);
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(MULTICAST_GROUP);
    socket.joinGroup(address);
    DatagramPacket packet;
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    socket.receive(packet);
    String rtn = new String(packet.getData());
    socket.leaveGroup(address);
    socket.close();
    return rtn;
}
```

It listens on the multicast group `224.0.0.224` and as soon as it receives a packet it closes the socket and returns the string from the packets byte array.

However as `socket.recieve()` is a blocking call, depending on your requirements you should call the client method from a Separate thread or task, and have some time-out mechanism. Without further details of your system its hard to say what would be best.

Comment: Calling leaveGroup() just before close() is redundant.